# BC30311: Value of Type 'faq' cannot be converted to 'FAQ'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-entities

really stuck on this one. The logic doesn't seem to be different from any other Linq to Entity logic I have in the rest of my application. I'm simply writing data into a table called FAQ using Linq to Entity. But I get the message BC30311: Value of Type 'faq' cannot be converted to 'FAQ'. I can't work out what value it means.

```
    Dim objQuestion As TextBox = gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFooterQuestion")
    Dim objAnswer As TextBox = gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFooterAnswer")
    Dim objCategory As TextBox = gvDetails.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFooterCategory")

    Using DBContext As New fundmatrixEntities
        Dim queryFAQ = DBContext.FAQs
        Dim oFAQ As New FAQ
        queryFAQ.Add(oFAQ)
        oFAQ.FAQId = 5
        oFAQ.Question = objQuestion.Text
        oFAQ.Answer = objAnswer.Text
        oFAQ.Category = objCategory.Text
        oFAQ.DateCreated = Date.Now
        oFAQ.DateUpdated = Date.Now
        Try
            DBContext.SaveChanges()
            BindEmployeeDetails()
            lblresult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green
            lblresult.Text = "details inserted successfully"
        Catch ex As Exception
            lblresult.Text = "There was problem inserting the FAQ!"
            lblresult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        End Try

    End Using
```

Comment: Which line gives the error?  Can you show the code for the FAQ/faq class(es)?

Comment: Thanks for responding Chris. the line errors on "queryFAQ.Add(oFAQ)". 

Partial Public Class FAQ
Public Property FAQId As Integer
Public Property Question As String
Public Property Answer As String
Public Property Category As String
Public Property DateCreated As Date
Public Property DateUpdated As Date]

Comment: Could it be because the table has an identity seed on it? Then again even without the faqid the error still appears. Secondly if I do a build, it fails but no error appears, only when I do a rebuild solution.

Comment: This error almost certainly doesn't have anything to do with the identity seed.  Could there be more than one class called faq?  Perhaps one defined by EF and one that you have created?

Comment: Yes you're right. I had a page called  faq.aspx which has a codebehind class called faq. Thank you so much! If you can post as an answer I'd be happy to mark it. Once again, thank you.